# Are the fixed points of a continuous map from a compact, convex subset of the Euclidean space to itself always isolated? If not, is there a condition?

Tags: differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact, convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f: C\to C$ be a continuous map *that's not the identity map* (see Qiaochu Yuan's comment below). If necessary here, assume differentiable, smooth, analytic... etc. We know by [Brouwer's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) that $f$ must have a fixed point.

**My questions are:**

(1) Are the fixed points of $f$ isolated even if $f$ is smooth, real analytic etc.? I understand that fixed points are isolated is equivalent to saying that the fixed points are finite.

(2) **If not, is there a condition on $f$ that guarantees that the fixed points of $f$ are isolated?**

EDIT: for question (1), we can use the examples of rotation around a fixed axis in a ball, as given by Qiaochu Yuan below; another example is:

$$f:B^2\to B^2:= f(x,y):=(x,y^2)$$

Note that here $x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \implies y^2 \le 1 \implies y^4 \le y^2 
 \implies x^2 + y^4 \le 1.$ Now here $f(x,y)=(x,y) \implies y^2=y \implies y= 0,1 \implies $ the fixed points of $f$ are the set of all $(x,0)$ and srt of all $(x,1), 0\le x \le 1.$ So the fixed point set is not isolated.

Comment: No, e.g. $f$ could be the identity. More interesting examples are also possible, e.g. consider rotating a solid ball which leaves invariant the axis of rotation. This ought to be true "generically" though.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, I'm modifying the question to exclude the identity case.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for that example! What did you mean by 'This ought to be true "generically" though'

Comment: Here's some further quick counterexamples of (1). Suppose that $D \subset C$ is *any* nonempty, compact, convex subset. Define $f : C \to D$ by requiring that for each $p \in C$, the point $f(p) \in D$ is the unique point of $D$ closest to $p$. One does have to prove that such a point exists, and that $f$ is continuous. Once that is done, note that $f$ fixes each point of $D$.

Comment: Also, any one example of a $f : C \to C$ with nonempty fixed point set $P \subset C$ can be converted into more examples. Choose a self-homeomorphism $g : C \to C$, and let $f_1 = g \circ f \circ g^{-1} : C \to C$; then the fixed point set of $f_1$ is $g(P)$.

Comment: A reasonable conjecture is that there exists an open and dense subset consisting of such maps.

Comment: (2) has the trivial answer "yes": the condition that $f$ has isolated fixed points guarantees that the fixed points of $f$ are isolated. To find a more useful answer, consider $g(x) = f(x) - x$. $g$ has zeros exactly where $f$ has fixed points. What conditions can you put on $g$ to ensure that its zeros are isolated? Quite famously, smoothness is not sufficient. Neither is real-analycity for $n > 1$, as has already been seen. "Harmonic" might be sufficient, but that is getting very restrictive.